# Rails: Get Posts of Users within 10km of a point

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, geokit

I'm using the rails 3 geokit gem that allows you to find users within a distance of a point, e.g.

```
User.within(10, origin: [51.123123, 0.1323123])
```

['10' is the distance in mi/km; 51 & 0 are latitude and longitude]

I'm now trying to **get all posts by users who are within a certain distance** of a point. something like:

```
Post.where(User.within(10, origin: [51.123123, 0.1323123]))
```

(my Post model belongs_to my User model, my User model has_many posts)

Reading around it seems like the solution lies in .where, or using :through & :source, or .joins, but I haven't been able to nail it down.

I'd be very grateful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
class Post
  acts_as_mappable through: :user
end

Post.joins(:user).within(10, origin: [51.123123, 0.1323123])
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be a more elegant solution, but I think the simplest may be to use IN with SQL. Do something like:

```
Post.where(["user_id IN (?)", User.within(10, origin: [51.123123, 0.1323123]).map { |u| u.id }])
```

Basically, you're just sending an array of `user_ids` that `Post.user_id` could match.

Comment: This works! Thank you. I agree though, it does seem like rails has a more conventional solution somewhere

Comment: The `.map` part is not necessary. This is enough: `Post.where(user_id: User.within(10, origin: [51.123123, 0.1323123]))`.

Comment: Sorry micha, this doesn't work, I get 'ActionView::Template::Error (PGError: ERROR:  subquery has too many columns
LINE 1: ...CT COUNT(*) FROM "posts"  WHERE "posts"."user_id" IN (SELECT...'

Answer (score 1):

If your User model `has_many` posts, why don't you just load them directly?

```
@posts = User.within(10, origin: [51.123123, 0.1323123]).collect(&:posts).flatten
```

[`collect`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-collect) is a synonym for `map`, it effectively transforms an array into another array applying a transforming method or a block to every element of the original array.

In our command above, `within` is a named scope that returns an array of `Users`, `collect` applys the method `posts` to each user, thereby generating an array of posts per user. Finally, `flatten` takes the array of posts arrays (its a 2 dimensional array) and squishes it into one big array of posts.

You could also have a default `includes` in your `User` model to prevent the [N+1 query problem.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) while loading `Posts`.

FWIW, I prefer using ActiveRecord methods (associations, etc.) instead of using raw SQL where possible.

Comment: I'm not familiar with .collect so forgive me if I'm doing something wrong - using this line as @posts that I then loop through in the view does not work...

Comment: I have added more details to my answer. Hope this helps! 

Sorry for the terse answer before :)

Comment: this is not efficient at all, for each user user you have to make query for posts.

Comment: ...it doesn't work for me though! I get 'NoMethodError (undefined method `search' for #<Array:0x007f8fe1775650>):'. In fact my line looks like this: User.within(1000, origin: @userlocation).collect(&:posts).flatten.search(params[:search]).order('created_at desc').paginate(per_page: 7, page: params[:page]) .... but search, order and paginate work just fine on jbarket's .map solution above... and should here too no?

Comment: Bottomline: TIMTOWTDI  @YuriBarbashov i agree your method is more efficient. The associated posts can be eager loaded via `includes` for some efficiency gains.

@user1362141 thats because the 'search' method is not defined for `Array`s :) 

Either ways, I didn't mean to suggest that my answer is the 'best'.

Comment: Thank you CubaLibre - apologies, rookie-hour over here. So using Yuri's method now ATposts = Post.joins(:user).merge(User.within(1000, origin: [51.123123, 0.1323123])).search(params[:search]).order('created_at desc').paginate(per_page: 7, page: params[:page])
      ...I get 'ActionView::Template::Error (missing attribute: user_id):' when I try to call the post.user_id in a loop through ATposts in the view... Is this a similar issue as with your method: Yuri's code is not returning something that is compatible with search, order etc?

Answer (score 0):

```
Post.joins(:user).merge(User.within(10, origin: [51.123123, 0.1323123]))
```

Comment: this looks like exactly what I need! But i'm getting this error currently: "ActionView::Template::Error (Association named 'users' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?)"

Comment: @user1362141, that's because it should be `Post.joins(:user)` instead of `Post.joins(:users)`.

Comment: I don't think `merge` is appropriate here. Should just be `where` IMO.

Comment: @Mischa IMO `where` is not appropriate here and `merge` is appropriate

Comment: Yuri, this still isn't working for me i'm afraid. I now get the error 'ActionView::Template::Error (missing attribute: user_id):' when the first post is called in the view...

Comment: Hm, maybe you're right. Could you explain why, because the [API](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge) does not give much info?